# Typescript dynamic logo

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript so I apologize if this is a very simple question. I'm trying to create a utility file that would help me quickly get the logo I need for different React components that will show the app logo.

Currently this is my code:

```js
import full from '../../assets/logo/logo-full.jpg';
import flat from '../../assets/logo/logo-flat.jpg';

const logo = (style: string): full | flat | null => {
    switch(style) {
        case 'full':
            return full;
        
        case 'flat':
            return flat;
    }

    return null;
};

export default logo;
```

Currently I'm getting these error messages:

> Cannot use namespace 'full' as a type. ts(2709)
> Cannot use namespace 'flat' as a type. ts(2709)

My questions are:

- How do I define the expected return values of this function *(may return either the full logo or the flat logo, or a null value)*?
- How do I limit the accepted parameters to just `full` or `flat` instead of opening it up to any `string`?

### Additional Info

I already added the following:

```js
declare module '*.jpg' {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}
```

Comment: Try this = (style: string): typeof full | typeof flat | null.
Basically the typeof full should be a string.

Comment: I dont think you need declare module at all. You are using CRA right?